# Oracle patch for 19.9."You do not have the required access privilege to download this patch."

Tags: oracle, patch, oracle19c

I am using oracle19.3. I want to download the oracle19.9 patch from oracle's website, but it seems to show that I don't have permission to download it. What should I do?
[image: You do not have the required access privilege to download this patch. This patch has been superseded. Please see the reason stated below.]

Comment: I guess you'll have to download the patch that has superseded it instead. It's possible they'll let you have that specific file if you've paid for a certain level of support, or they've withdrawn that version completely and it's not longer available at all e.g. because of a serious problem or vulnerability in it. But you'll have to ask Oracle not us - we can only speculate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be a support/license issue that should be discussed with Oracle support